# How to make some part of select list text bold and some normal font in React

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have to create a select list to show some product in a select. The list should show product name but there should be a count in bold text like this:
[image: please see this image to understand the question]

What I have tried is I am creating an array of the products and pushing my product in it along with product and count like this:

`productInformation.push(currentProdName + " (" + cnt + " Product" + ")");`

After that I am mapping it to json and binding it to select list like this:

```
var jsonProducts = productInformation.map(function (key, value) {
   return { value: key, label: key }
});


<Select  id="productName" name="productName" options={jsonProducts}  
   onChange={onSelectChange}  
   placeholder={"All Products ("+supplierProducts.length + ")"} 
   ref={productInputRef}  
   styles={{menu: provided => ({ ...provided, zIndex: 9999 }) }} />
```

But by doing it this way, I am getting result like this: [image: please see what currently i am achiving]

**How can I make count and product text bold in this?**

Comment: Hello, it's hard to read the code sample, could you try formatting it better, please?

Comment: sure will do it now

Comment: The `Select` component is some library `Select` component or does it render a classic html `select`? If it is a library, you can probably use HTML inside it, but a plain old select doesn't allow much styling. So the answer will very much depend on what `Select` is.

Comment: i am using  material ui its select of material ui

Comment: I added that tag and remove jquery since it did not appear to be in play here

Comment: I did a small bit for formatting and slight grammar changes - hopefully it enhances clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Import the "**MenuItem**" from the Mui library and use it as you would any other tag.

But before you should clean certain parts of your code before

```
productInformation.push({currentProdName, cnt});

var jsonProducts = productInformation.map(function (prod) {
   return <MenuItem value={prod.currentProdName+ " (" + prod.cnt + " Product" + ")"}>{prod.currentProdName}<b>&nbsp;{ "(" + prod.cnt + " Product" + ")"}</b></MenuItem>
});


<Select  id="productName" name="productName" onChange={onSelectChange}  
   placeholder={"All Products ("+supplierProducts.length + ")"} 
   ref={productInputRef}  
   styles={{menu: provided => ({ ...provided, zIndex: 9999 }) }} >

  {jsonProducts}
</Select>
```

As you can see you'll have to fill the data in **MenuItem** and then add the object to the Select.
I changed how the information is pushed into the *productInformation* array (for better control)
Note: I removed *jsonProducts* from *options* and into the inside of **Select** tag.

Comment: it wouldn't work ,  i have done that

Comment: @jsBuddy ahh i see, i'll edit for something that should work

Comment: Now list is coming blank

Comment: i also did  options={jsonProducts} in select list still its blank

Comment: @jsBuddy did you remove the options ?

Comment: yeah i try with both , with & without options=

Comment: @jsBuddy have you changed anything ? when you click on the Select, do you not get a list ?!

Comment: no list is not loading  i followed with exactly your code

Comment: @jsBuddy This is working so there might be something else ! Debug and see if the array is being filled

Answer (score 0):

I am slightly out of my expertise area here on MUI and React but something like: (note I did not have access to your original JSON/JavaScript object for the `p.count` here but perhaps you can work with this:

```
<CustomSelect>
  <StyledOption value={}>"All Products ({supplierProducts.length})"</StyledOption>
  {jsonProducts.map((p) => (
  <StyledOption value={c.value}>
    {p.label} <span style="font-weight:bold;">({p.count}) Products</span>
  </StyledOption>
  ))}
</CustomSelect>
```

Reference: https://mui.com/components/selects/

Answer (score 0):

As you are mapping jsonProducts from `productInformation` array
i would suggest

```
  let content = (<div >{ProductName}<b> {" (" + Count+ " Product" + ") "}</b></div>);
productInformation.push(content);
```

now map it as it is

```
var jsonProducts = productInformation.map(function (key, value) {
   return { value: key, label: key }
});
```